# Best way to test DB calls to Access

Tags: .net, testing, transactions, oledb

I have a Windows Forms application that have a Access database as repository. So I use OLEDB instead of ADODB. I want to write unit tests to test my methods making calls to the DB. The reason is I want to be able to test my SQL queries easy. When testing updates, deletes and inserts my first thought was using Transactionscope. But then I realized it was not supported by OLEDB. I know I can use oledbtransaction but that requires an open connection which I don't have in the test method.

What's is the best way(s) to accomplish my crud methods? I don't want the tests to change data in the DB.

Edit1)
I want to test the DB calls to make sure the SQL statements are correct. I have two classes, one for Access (OLEDB) and one for SQLServer (ADO) that have the same methods (implements the same interface). I do this to be able to use the application against both SQL Azure and a local Access Db. Access and SQL server don't use the same syntax/functions all the time. It is also much easier to test the db code from a test instead of running the whole application.

I guess I could have an open connection but I don't want to expose this connection to the user of my datalayer class. Also, it's two different connection classes. A client (and test method) shall only know about the interface the class implement.

I have also thought about copying the database. But it will get quite many copies since several tests need to update/insert into the same table. That way I need to keep track of what is updated/inserted so I don't add duplicates and update already updated data. To avoid that I need to copy the db for each test method.

Comment: Why can't you have an open connection? Also, I don't really get why you want to test these methods but if you are and don't want them actually changing the data in the database, why not just make a local copy and test the methods on that?

Comment: Are you testing just for yourself as a programmer to debug your code? Or is the user doing the testing?

Comment: Then I would say you should definitely just make a local copy of the database. I don't think you need to make separate copies for all the different tests you want to do either. Just test one command, check the results, then move on to testing the next command.